# Does ServiceController.WaitForStatus set the status or just wait?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, .net-4.6, servicecontroller

I'm using `ServiceController.WaitForStatus` for the first time to limit time wasted on trying to start services that won't start. My assumption is to use it like this:

```
var sc = new ServiceController(_monitoredService);
var seconds = _startWaitTimeout / 1000;
sc.Start();
sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, seconds));
if (sc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
{
    _logger.Warn($"'{_monitoredService}' did not start within {seconds} seconds.");
}
```

Then a little devil on my shoulder suggested that `WaitForStatus` might take it upon itself to attempt to set the status before waiting. Does it?

Comment: [No](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/35st9aw1(v=vs.110).aspx). From Docs: *Use WaitForStatus to suspend an application's processing until the service has reached the required status.* Thats all.

Comment: @makadev Make that an answer then, and I'll accept.

Comment: What's with the down-vote, little man? I didn't know if *required status* meant the one in the call to `WaitForStatus`, or one in a prior status setting call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

[From MSDN Documentations:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/35st9aw1(v=vs.110).aspx)
*Use WaitForStatus to suspend an application's processing until the service has reached the required status.*

Thats all, it only suspends the calling thread and polls the status - as mentioned in the Documentation - every some 250ms until either Service State or Timeout is reached.